# what is the fastest way to update a table based on select without arising a race condition and performance?

Tags: oracle

Thanks in advance. I need help to update a record based on select which holds millions of data ,  as shown below

```
UPDATE order_consumed
SET
    status = 'consumed',
    last_modified_dt = systimestamp,
    customer_id = (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            company
        WHERE
            company_name =:company_name
    )
WHERE
    id = ( SELECT MAX(id)   FROM ma_available_order_v WHERE ebs_ordernumber = :order_number)
AND
    status <> 'CONSUMED'
```

The view ma_available_order_v is a view contains the combination of 4 tables including the one which we updating the  order_consumed.In single instance, the query executes in less than one second, but in parallel, it is taking time to 6 seconds. There are many blogs which give the explanation to update millions of record, but my case is to update one record based on the select which holds millions of values and this will execute many numbers of times simultaneously.

```
Is there any way to maximise the performance? like to update one record based on select which has millions of record? 

Note: sorry to make the query in a more macro level, the table and indexes are intact. It would help if you can help me in constructing the query in a more optimised way or any pl/SQL block is needed.
```

Comment: use merge update

Answer (score 0):

> ...without arising a race condition ...

So, you have multiple processes performing this logic at the same time?

If so, you probably want to introduce PL/SQL so that you can have the control (over fetching) that you need to make sure each process pulls the 1st unconsumed record that hasn't already been picked up (i.e., locked) by another process.

Also,

> ... with performance ...

You probably want to add an index to `ORDER_CONSUMED` to give Oracle an access path to get the latest, unconsumed records quickly without a full scan of the table.

Here is how you can put those two ideas together:

```
-- Create a function-based index that has the IDs of the unconsumed rows only.
CREATE INDEX order_consumed_n1 ON order_consumed 
    ( DECODE(status,'consumed',null,id) );


DECLARE
  CURSOR c IS SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(5) */ rowid 
              FROM   order_consumed 
              WHERE DECODE(status,'consumed',null,id) is not null 
              ORDER BY DECODE(status,'consumed',null,id) DESC 
              -- If Oracle tries to fetch a row and finds it is locked, 
              -- skip it and move onto the next one.
              FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
  l_rowid_to_update ROWID;
BEGIN
  OPEN c;
  -- No LOOP, just fetch the 1st record.  The SKIP LOCKED in the cursor
  -- will ensure that we don't wait for other sessions.  The record we
  -- fetch will be locked by our session as it is fetched (due to FOR UPDATE
  -- in cursor)
  FETCH c INTO l_rowid_to_update;
  -- Update the record
  UPDATE order_consumed
  SET    status = 'consumed',
         last_modified_dt = systimestamp,
         customer_id = 100  -- Your customer ID logic here...
  WHERE  rowid = l_rowid_to_update;

  COMMIT;
END;
```